# Azure AD B2C as Oracle Fusion ERP IDP

Tags: oracle, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, saml, idp

We have a bunch of Oracle applications that we would like to integrate with Azure AD B2C IDP with SSO. Has anyone used Azure AD B2C as IDP for Oracle Fusion and similar apps? It is possible out of the box with Azure AD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/oracle-fusion-erp-tutorial
but cannot find any documentation on B2C.

I understand we could do it the general way as we do by registering a SAML SP https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers.

Would like to check with the experts on any better way for this or if there could be any drawbacks on this. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the SAML SP approach works.

I've done a number of these e.g. [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-the-componentspace-saml-2-0-stack-to-azure-ad-b2c-c6e8288eeb4b).

The biggest problem is mapping the B2C user to the application. You would have to ensure that Oracle recognises the B2C user (NameID) as B2C users can have any email - not necessarily domain-joined.

Also, a B2C user can be a simple user name e.g. JoeB or a phone number depending on how you set it up.

Comment: would you have any examples that uses a commercial SaaS product as the SP?

Comment: No, but you could take any Azure AD enterprise application docs and get the info. from that and apply the parameters e.g. entityID as per my post above.

Comment: From this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/oracle-fusion-erp-provisioning-tutorial#connector-limitations, it says "roles in Oracle Fusion ERP are mapped to groups in Azure AD."  I cannot find any documentation of the names of these roles.  Anyone has any idea whether ERP fusion roles can be assigned by mapping them with AAD groups? @shaswatapal any help appreciated!